# Recursive XSD Help

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xsd2code

i'm trying to learn a little bit XSD and I'm trying to create a XSD for this xml:

```
<Document>
  <TextBox Name="Username" />
  <TextBox Name="Password" />
</Document>
```

... so there's an element, which is an abstract complex type. Every element have elements and so on. `Document` and `TextBox` are extending `Element`.

I trid this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Element">

        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Element" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Element" type="Element"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TextBox">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Element">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I compiled it to C# with Xsd2Code, and now I try to deserialize it:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));

var document = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream("Document1.xml", FileMode.Open));

foreach (var element in document.Element1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((TextBox)element).Name);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

and it dosen't print anything. When I try to serialize it like so:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));

var document = new Document();

document.Element1 = new List<Element>();

document.Element1.Add(new TextBox()
{
    Name = "abc"
});

serializer.Serialize(new FileStream("d.xml", FileMode.Create), document);
```

...the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Element1>
    <Element xsi:type="TextBox">
      <Element1 />
      <Name>abc</Name>
    </Element>
  </Element1>
</Document>
```

When it should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TextBox Name="abc" />
</Document>
```

Any ideas how to fix the xsd or another code generator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the XSD code, look at the line where you declare an element named "Element". This element should be named as such `<xs:element name="TextBox" />` if you want to use `<TextBox/>` in your XML files.

With the above change implemented, you could run `xsd.exe /c YourFile.xsd` to generate a C# class from the XSD. Include the generated file in your C# project and you'll be able to use it like this:

```
  Document d = new Document();
  d.TextBox = new TextBox[]
  {
    new TextBox() { Name = "Username" },
    new TextBox() { Name = "Password" },
  };
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));            
  ser.Serialize(Console.Out, d);
```

You'll also be able to deserialize the XML back into C# objects.

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TextBox xsi:type="TextBox" Name="Username" />
  <TextBox xsi:type="TextBox" Name="Password" />
</Document>
```

Note the `xsi:type` attribute - because you declared your `TextBox` element to be of type `Element` you will have to provide which concrete type implementation to use when deserializing one of these elements. Out of curiosity I tried changing the XSD type of the element named TextBox to the TextBox type, but `xsd.exe` threw a StackOverflowException. I chuckled. It probably to do with the recursive type relationship between Element and TextBox, but maybe a different tool would handle it differently?